# Terminating exception type of NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, nsexception

I am receiving the following error when compiling my code. I am trying to connect to a sqlite 3 database and upon text entered into the UIAlertView save that to the table, creating a new list.Any and all help is much appreciated I have spent hours trying to figure out why this error is getting thrown because the sql file is in the project and was created using sqlitebrowser.

```
2014-12-04 19:10:29.917 SmartShop[7964:60b] -[DBManager initWithDatabaseFile:]:                                              unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109239910
2014-12-04 19:10:29.925 SmartShop[7964:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DBManager initWithDatabaseFile:]: unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x109239910'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a35495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010179499e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ac665d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a26d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a26938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   SmartShop                           0x0000000100001c62 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 114
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010043759e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100437777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001007422e2 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 390
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010037dffa -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1109
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010037db9f -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 36
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010037daef -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 101
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010037cdfe -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 377
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010043b70a -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 147
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100377b1b -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 490
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100377c70 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000100380ffa -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010033cc98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1788
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000100340a0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100351d4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000100352216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000100342086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103bae71a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103bae1e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019b7679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019b744e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019e0903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019dfd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001003402e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000100341e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    30  SmartShop                           0x0000000100002563 main + 115
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101fba5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Below is my code from the ViewController referencing the SQLite3 db and other code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DBManager.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize the dbManager object.
    self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFile:@"shop.sql.sqbpro"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)addNewList:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add List" message:@"Enter              new list name:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Add" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *alertTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.placeholder = @"List name";
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *listName = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    NSLog(@"ENTERED: %@",listName);

    //Prepare the query String
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into lists values(null, '%@')", listName];

    //Execute the query
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

    //If successful pop the view controller
    if(self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

        //Pop view controller
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
    }
}
@end
```

Finally below is my code for initWithDatabaseFileName:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)dbFilename{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Set the documents directory path to the documentsDirectory property.
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // Keep the database filename.
        self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

        // Copy the database file into the documents directory if necessary.
        [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `initWithDatabaseFile:` but the name of the method is `initWithDatabaseFilename:`.

Make sure your .h file for `DBManager` has the correct name matching the actual method in the .m file.

Comment: That was it, the header file was referencing the wrong method name. Thank you for pointing out something so simple. I guess I was looking at it too long and missed the easy answer. Thanks so much it is much appreciated!!